# How to locate the position that c++ exception was originally thrown?

Tags: c++, ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

We get some logs from Fabric/Crashlytics looks like the following, we know that it is caused by out of range of
std::map<>, but this does not help much, all the original information are lost, is there any way to locate where the
exception is thrown from?

```
#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  Foo Bar                        0x102874c04 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4577168
1  Foo Bar                        0x102874c04 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4577168
2  Foo Bar                        0x102874ac0 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4576844
3  Foo Bar                        0x102864810 CLSHandler + 4510620
4  Foo Bar                        0x102872c1c __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4569000
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1807ed048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1807f5ae8 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  Foo Bar                        0x1028726b0 CLSExceptionRecord + 4567612
8  Foo Bar                        0x1028721c0 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4566348
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x1800a754c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1800a75b8 std::terminate() + 60
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800b876c _destroyAltHandlerList + 10
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1807ed05c _dispatch_client_callout + 36
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1807f46c8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
14 FrontBoardServices             0x1835499f4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
15 FrontBoardServices             0x183549698 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
16 FrontBoardServices             0x183549c34 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
17 CoreFoundation                 0x180e122e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
18 CoreFoundation                 0x180e12268 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
19 CoreFoundation                 0x180e11af0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
20 CoreFoundation                 0x180e0f6c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
21 CoreFoundation                 0x180d2ffb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
22 GraphicsServices               0x182bc7f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
23 UIKit                          0x18a3042f4 UIApplicationMain + 208
24 Foo Bar                        0x1021c916c main (main.m:6)
25 libdyld.dylib                  0x18085256c start + 4

--

Fatal Exception: std::out_of_range: map::at:  key not found
```

Comment: it was originally thrown at `map::at`. I guess you want to know where that was called

Comment: Hi! Can you let me know what version of our SDK you are using? It looks like you might be using an old version. Thanks!